# jQuery and first element in the clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have 2 **div** elements, and if i click on the first div then should the other div which is inside of the clicked div displayed, but i can't understand who it works, my jquery code is so:

```
jQuery('.infobutton').click(function(){
    var clickedID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery(clickedID).children('div').toggle(); 
});

<div class="infobutton" id="infobtn1">
    <div class="content">some content</div>
</div>
```

I get everytime right id, i tried also with `.first()`, `.parent()`, `.children('.content')`

It's possible to do this with jQuery?

Comment: <div class="infobutton" id="infobtn1">
<div class="content">some content</div>
</div>

Comment: `$("infobtn1")` is not the correct selector for selecting an element by ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's presume you have HTML like this:

```
<div id="container" class="infobutton">
    Some content
    <div>Some other content</div>
</div>
```

Now let's walk through your Javascript:

```
jQuery('.infobutton').click(function(){
```

Find elements with the class `infobutton` and assign a `click` handler. This works fine.

```
var clickedID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
```

Put the `id` of that element in the variable `clickedID`. The value of `clickedID` is now `container`.

```
jQuery(clickedID).children('div').toggle();
```

Run the jQuery selector on `clickedID`. **Here we have the problem.** This can be boiled down to `jQuery('container')`. This looks for an element with the tag name `container`, not with the ID `container`.

In fact, the solution to all of this is not to use the ID at all. Instead, you can build the jQuery object with `this`, which is a reference to the clicked element:

```
jQuery('.infobutton').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).children('div').toggle(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the event handler `this` will refer the element to which the handler was attached to

```
jQuery('.infobutton').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).children('.content').toggle(); 
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xp7GB/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

```
jQuery('.infobutton').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).children('.content').toggle(); 
});
```

`this` refers to the current element inside the event .

your code will work as

use `jQuery('#'+clickedID)`  instead of `jQuery(clickedID)`